# using mongdb in react app producing webpack5 error

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am developing a frontend element for a web3 project and all was well until I tried to add the MongoDB library, to allow calls to the database on MongoDB atlas, intially I got a load of errors around the webpack 5 Breaking change caused by the lack of polyfil.
I followed this guide https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#troubleshooting-and-known-issues which removed lots of the errors.

However I am stuck with the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js 10:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '~/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js 12:28-58
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 83:23-48 464:21-46
 @ ./src/App.jsx 21:0-38 51:21-32
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 30:37-40

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js 20:12-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in '~/node_modules/native-dns-cache'
 @ ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/index.js 3:0-50 4:0-60 5:0-68
 @ ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/platform.js 27:12-39
 @ ./node_modules/native-dns/dns.js 22:0-44
 @ ./node_modules/dns/lib/dns.js 3:12-33
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/srv_polling.js 8:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 707:20-49
 @ ./src/App.jsx 21:0-38 51:21-32
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 30:37-40

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/platform.js 22:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '~/node_modules/native-dns/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/native-dns/dns.js 22:0-44
 @ ./node_modules/dns/lib/dns.js 3:12-33
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/srv_polling.js 8:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 707:20-49
 @ ./src/App.jsx 21:0-38 51:21-32
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 30:37-40

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js 22:12-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in '~/node_modules/native-dns/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/native-dns/dns.js 23:0-59 24:0-65 25:0-65
 @ ./node_modules/dns/lib/dns.js 3:12-33
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/srv_polling.js 8:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 707:20-49
 @ ./src/App.jsx 21:0-38 51:21-32
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 30:37-40

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/utils.js 20:12-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in '~/node_modules/native-dns/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js 26:16-44 27:16-44
 @ ./node_modules/native-dns/dns.js 23:0-59 24:0-65 25:0-65
 @ ./node_modules/dns/lib/dns.js 3:12-33
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/srv_polling.js 8:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 707:20-49
 @ ./src/App.jsx 21:0-38 51:21-32
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 30:37-40

ERROR in ./node_modules/saslprep/lib/memory-code-points.js 3:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '~/node_modules/saslprep/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/saslprep/index.js 10:4-39
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js 57:2-40
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js 437:13-30
 @ ./src/App.jsx 21:0-38 51:21-32
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 30:37-40
```

Any suggestions on how I fix these?
It all seems to be related to the mongodb import as commenting the import out removes the issue.

Comment: the MongoDB client can only be used in server-side JavaScript. You can use Node.js or Deno for this. It is not possible to use MongoDb in React(client-side)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB runs on a node.js server not ReactJs

https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial